# OpenLayers 5: remove map animation

Tags: openlayers

Using [Putting content of popup into modal using OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329448) I am now able to put the content of a popup into a  modal of Bootstrap 4.

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element:  document.getElementById('myModal'),
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
    new ol.control.ScaleLine({className: 'ol-scale-line', target: document.getElementById('scale-line')}),
  ]),
  layers: [
    OpenStreetMap,
    istat,
  ],
  overlays: [overlay],
  target: 'map',
    render: 'canvas',
  view: new ol.View({
    extent: boundary,
    center: center,
    zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 14
  })
});

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  clickFeature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });
  if (clickFeature) {
    var element = overlay.getElement();
    overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    $(element).modal('show');
  }
});
```

> @TomazicM provided part of this code

The problem now is the animation of the map that is activated after the click on the geometry. If I click on a geometry the modal opens and the map moving down. In other words happens a thing similar of the use the pan function for navigate the map.

[image]

How I can remove this?

Comment: Add pertinent code to your question, otherwise answering is just quessing.

Comment: Is the same code of the linked post. I anyway must add it?

Comment: Yes, otherwise context of the qustion is not clear and it could also go to infinity: linked page could have link to another page and so on ...

Comment: Ok, I do this in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution!

I've changed this:

```
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element:  document.getElementById('myModal'),
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
});
```

with this:

```
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element:  document.getElementById('myModal'),
  autoPan: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Map shouldn't move if you place your modal `div` definition outside map `div`:

```
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    ...
  </div>
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've added an image for give a better comprehension of my problem. The div already exist before the modal

Comment: Since it works OK for me, it's hard to say what's wrong in your case without seeing your complete code.